# Welcome, then black screen, then Ctrl+Alt+Del on new Windows 7 login

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, login, domain, ctrl-alt-delete

Need help troubleshooting an interesting login issue.

Workstation is an OptiPlex 3010 running Windows 7 Pro.

Returning user to our company, when she tries to sign in using her reactivated account, she's able to reset her password, and the screen spins on Welcome. Then from her perspective the screen goes black for a second or two, then returns to the Ctrl+Alt+Del lock screen. Historically this kind of issue has been caused by either a full hard drive (not enough space on the disk to generate local account) or having another user currently logged into the system (a "feature" of our antivirus software). Neither of these causes are present on the system.

Interestingly, Event Viewer is showing that her account successfully logs into the system at the timestamps when we've tried logging her in.

So far I've:

1. Confirmed her account can log into a computer in our office after a password reset
2. Confirmed that my non-admin account can generate a local profile on her computer
3. Unjoined and rejoined the computer to our domain
4. Removed her local profile by deleting her profile registry key under ProfileList and deleting her Users folder
5. Confirmed that there isn't a conflict with her AD groups and the computer's AD groups (if this was the case there would be an error message)

So far I haven't tried having her log into another computer at her location due to lack of availability, but I would think successfully logging her account in on a computer in our office would debunk her account being the issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the domain (if it's like wifi controlled)? Sometimes it gets mixed up (I've dealt with em before). Has there been any recent Windows updates? Sometimes Windows Updates will break PC features (unknown bugs?). Has someone messed with the antivirus? If it's features have that, then it can lock the PC. Is it only this one user? If so, try to get all data off somehow, delete the user from the domain, recreate it, and then try. Has an admin/support person looked at it? If it's every user and they (tech/admin) mess with explorer.exe any way shape or form, then you can see a cursor only. explorer.exe is the Windows shell. Can you open task manager without loggin out? If so, open task manager, go to open task, and type into the run box "explorer.exe" without the quotes. Also, welcome to superuser!

Comment: 1) Restart the domain as in the domain controller? Unfortunately unable to do that.
2) I didn't check the Windows updates, thanks for the suggestion.
3) End users don't have access to the AV
4) Other users on the machine are fine, can't wipe it remotely for fear of losing other info
5) I'm the admin/support person
6) Can't get logged onto their user to do troubleshooting specific to them

Comment: Any luck so far?